# I´m having trouble applying conditional formatting with this script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

I have a series of spreadsheets on google sheets consolidating several informations of a health care service. I was asked to improve the sheets readability, puting color coded formatting according to some pre-established patterns.

So I took a spreadsheet containing the data in question and added a pattern sheet to be the checking source of values. So I came up with this code.

```
function onOpen() {
  const planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const abaPadrao = planilha.getSheetByName('Padrao');
  const abas = planilha.getSheets(); // Obtém todas as abas da planilha

  abas.forEach(aba => {
    if (aba.getName() !== 'Padrao') { // Ignora a aba "Padrao"
      const valoresPadrao = abaPadrao.getRange('B3:AC').getValues(); // Valores da tabela "Padrao"
      const valoresAba = aba.getDataRange().getValues(); // Valores da aba ativa
      const cabecalhoAba = 4; // Número de linhas de cabeçalho na aba ativa

      for (let i = cabecalhoAba; i < valoresAba.length; i++) {
        const linhaAba = valoresAba[i];
        const linhaPadrao = valoresPadrao[i - cabecalhoAba];

        for (let j = 2; j < linhaAba.length; j++) { // Começa da coluna C
          const celulaAba = aba.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
          if (linhaAba[j] !== linhaPadrao[j - 2]) {
            celulaAba.setFontColor('red').setBackground('white');
          } else {
            celulaAba.setFontColor('black').setBackground('white');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And got some issues.
1 - The conditional formatting on google sheets overrides the script
2 - When disabling the contitional formatting I got all the cells in red and white except from just a few in black and white, even tough I checked up cell by cell comparing the contents.
3 - even changing the rule of formatting I did not  get expected result

I can´t look anymore this code and can´t find my error if someone could shed some light to me.

I can give access to the sheets in question. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgvu2SFDx0qcj9zrWsnld4kF-YBFuTQzSIlGXuf6nKI/edit?usp=sharing)

When the data stored on any sheet is equal to data stored on 'padroes' the text formating should be black letters with white background. If different should format text as red letters in white background

Comment: So how about creating a [mcve] that's a little simple and inform us as to what it is supposed to look like when it's running correctly.  The chances are good you wont be back because buildig a simpler example that creates your problem will probably help you solve it.

Comment: In this comparison `if (linhaAba[j] !== linhaPadrao[j - 2]) ` are any of these Date objects? `!==` could compare 2 Objects and if they are not the same Object it will succeed, so every date comparison would equat to `!==`

Comment: @TheWizEd are you saying that I should use a simple comparison because this will compare the type of object and the content. I should compare only the content of the object. Like If CELL A =  "123" and CELL B = 123  using the !== this would be true and using != this shoud be false?

Comment: For the case you mention yes, javascript will some times coerce variables of different type to the same type to compare.  You can try it, but to be safe with Date objects it is often best to use the Date object method `valueOf()`, provided the time of each object is the same.